# Error AADB2C90080 Azure B2C authenticating on IOS simulator, not on physical device

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

My Xamarin Forms app authenticates using Azure AD B2C in the iOS simulators, but when I launch it from VS on the physical device, I get a token error:

Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalUiRequiredException: AADB2C90080: The provided grant has expired. Please re-authenticate and try again. Current time: 1548093233, Grant issued time: 1545587290, Grant expiration time: 1546796890
Correlation ID: 2003386b-64fe-4cf6-bc7d-e7b51ff37d89

My device is added to the Apple provisioning profile and I can't seem to find out the reason why. Any ideas?

Comment: Try to uninstall the application and then install it again.

Comment: Yup I tried that, but thanks @BrunoCaceiro. I wondered whether it may be picking up an old token from a previously installed version, so I uninstalled it. Same problem unfortunately.

Comment: tried uninstalling it and doing a hard reset of the device, Same problem.

Comment: Which version of VS you use,and android devices also not work?

Comment: Have not tried Android devices, I am concentrating on the ios side for now.

Comment: VS 2017 Version 15.9.5 (I should also point out that I have had successful deployments to a physical device before, also with Azure B2C).